# Does Apple Push Notification service use UDP or TCP?

Tags: iphone

Does Apple push use TCP or UDP to deliver messages from their servers to the device?

Comment: Documentation says it all. Care to take a look?

Comment: The title contains a grammatical error.  Maybe two.  I'm glad you added the clarification.

Comment: updated question to clarify.  Apples documentation does _not_ cover this end of the stack.

Comment: why does it matter if they guarantee delivery, it isn't like you can change it either way.

Comment: It funny to me when people down vote questions simply because they don't know the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Apple Push Notification Service Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html):

> Important: WiFi is used for push
>   notifications only if there is no
>   cellular connection or if the device
>   is an iPod touch. To receive
>   notifications via Wi-Fi, the device’s
>   display must be on (that is, it cannot
>   be sleeping) or it must be plugged in.
>   The WiFi transmitter must be on
>   outbound TCP port 5223 and must be
>   within effective range.

also:

> Sandbox and Production Environments
>
> To develop and deploy the provider
>   side of a client-server application,
>   you must get SSL certificates from the
>   iPhone Developer Program portal. Each
>   certificate is limited to a single
>   application, identified by its bundle
>   ID. Each certificate is also limited
>   to one of two development
>   environments, each with its own
>   assigned IP address:
>
> Sandbox: The sandbox environment is
>   used for initial development and
>   testing of the provider application.
>   It provides the same set of services
>   as the production environment,
>   although with a smaller number of
>   server units. The sandbox environment
>   also acts a virtual device, enabling
>   simulated end-to-end testing. You
>   access the sandbox environment at
>   gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com,
>   outbound TCP port 2195.
>
> Production: Use the production
>   environment when building the
>   production version of the provider
>   application. Applications using the
>   production environment must meet
>   Apple’s reliability requirements. You
>   access the production environment at
>   gateway.push.apple.com, outbound TCP
>   port 2195.

finally:

> General Provider Requirements
>
> As a provider you may communicate with
>   Apple Push Notification Service over a
>   binary interface. This interface is a
>   high-speed, high-capacity interface
>   for providers; it uses a streaming TCP
>   socket design in conjunction with
>   binary content. The binary interface
>   is asynchronous.
>
> The binary interface of the production
>   environment is available through
>   gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195; the
>   binary interface of the sandbox
>   (development) environment is available
>   through
>   gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port
>   2195. You may establish multiple, parallel connections to the same
>   gateway or to multiple gateway
>   instances.

Comment: Although the first part definitely suggests they use TCP.  The last two are talking from your server two Apple, not from Apple to the device.

Comment: Apple also lists port 5223 as TCP on their list of wellknown ports: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1629 The list is for push notifications for Mac FaceTime and the like, but it presumably uses the same protocol.

Comment: For future reference, the article can be found at this archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20100723071128/http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html, and no I don't think those are the only cases where Wi-Fi is used any more, since back then the devices would disconnect from Wi-Fi whenever possible (screen off) to save battery. Here's an article about the addresses apple may use now (including potentially all of 13.0.0.0/8): https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609